# Find the sum of the coefficients in the expansion of the given expression using Binomial Theorem.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The expression is :
$$(1-3x+x^2)^{111}$$

I tried treating $$(3x+x^2)$$ as one term to turn it into a binomial expression and expanding it to a few terms to see if i could find some pattern to use binomial properties. But that way the term $$(3x+x^2)$$ was further raised to indices.. So it would have taken hours to expand that particular term as well.. Which ofcourse indicated that i should've approached the problem differently. I am quite new to binomial theorem and combinatorics. So while providing answers please try, also, to provide derivations of the theorems/conclusions you use..

Comment: The sum of the coefficients of a polynomial is the polynomial evaluated at $x=1$, hence the answer is trivially $-1$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @ Jack D'Aurizio comment

The sum of the coefficients of a polynomial is the polynomial evaluated at $x=1$

$$(1-3+1)^{111}=-1$$